# $a_{n+1}=a_{n-1}-{4\over a_n}$ for $n>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_1=10, a_2=20$ and $a_{n+1}=a_{n-1}-{4\over a_n}$ for $n>1$

Find the smallest value of $k$ for which $a_k=0$

Comment: I think I have seen this question few days ago.

Answer (score 10):

Let's rewrite our equation as $a_n a_{n+1} = a_{n-1} a_n - 4$.  $a_1 a_2 = 200$, and $a_n a_{n+1}$ will decrease by $4$ each time, so $a_{51} a_{52} = 0$.

This means that $k = 52$.